# UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone doesn't work with UITableViewStyleGrouped

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

To hide separators in a UITableView, setting the separatorStyle property to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone works fine if the table style is UITableViewStylePlain. But, for me at least, it doesn't work if the table style is UITableViewStyleGrouped. Has anyone else seen (and hopefully solved) this problem?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't seem to work for me either. You could try

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

but that removes the outer borders as well.